# Dreamhost Wordpress https cert added now no access to site

Tags: wordpress, https, lets-encrypt, dreamhost

Used Dreamhost’s free Let’s Encrypt on my website. Now when I try to reach my Wordpress site I receive, Page not working - redirected you too many times. Domain and site are hosted on Dreamhost.

I used Let’s encrypt on my root domain on an empty Wordpress site and it worked. I made a subdomain off the main one, built out the content on the Wordpress site then tried to encrypt it and that’s when I can’t access it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the database URLs are being forced to use either WWW or non-WWW. And what the SSL does is add HTTPS and remove WWW, so it creates a loop.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003304711-Changing-all-URLs-in-your-WordPress-database